# SSRS - Duplicates in parent group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am getting duplicates in the parent group of my report and I cannot workout why. Any ideas on what I may have done wrong?

[image]

Comment: I would guess your row group isn't grouping by region. Show the reports design, including the rowgroup pane under the main design area and the grouping for each row group.